# WCF: How to execute background tasks on main IIS thread?

Tags: wcf

Suppose my WCF Service Application is "single-threaded" and I process some stuff on a background thread, but then need to service the processed data on the main IIS thread. (conversely, and seemingly more easily, I could lob all incoming methods to be re-called on the background thread, but this is not what I'm asking).

How can I, from the background thread, "notify" the main thread that my WCF methods are being invoked upon, to "wake up" and go process a method I specify?

I'm not super-familiar with the inner workings of WCF & IIS. I'm taking a guess that my service's methods are being called from completion ports and I should take as little time as possible in them, to prevent the IO servicing stuff from choking. I'm starting to think that if I want everything synchronized on one thread (calls to my methods, and my video-processing operations I need to perform), then I should make a command q and put all incoming method calls onto the command Q.

Surely this is an extremely common scenario. How do most people do this?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to run something in background, and process something else further based on the result from background job.

Maybe you can try the Task, which you can specify the callback (Task.ContinueWith) when the task is finished.